# How to load a grid from XAML codes and add it to a stackpanel dynamically/at runtime?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, runtime

I generate the XAML codes which actually describe a valid `grid` control - called the `GridXAML`. I want to create a grid object and add it to a stackpanel on my form.

How can I 1) create an object from its XAML string value, and 2) add it dynamically to a panel? Please help!

Giving a specific sample context as below.
The generated grid's xaml:

```
<Grid>
  <Textblock Text="abb" />
</Grid>
```

The current main form of my WPF application.

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="333" Width="111">
    <StackPanel x:Name="MyStackPanel" Orientation="Vertical">
        <!--I want the grid appear here at runtime-->
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

All helps are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx)'s [XamlReader.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.load.aspx) or XamlReader.Parse()

Comment: Can you make it more specific?